# Styling limitations in Ionic's date range picker due to Shadow DOM usage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I am currently working on customizing the date range picker in Ionic, but I have encountered some limitations with styling options due to the usage of Shadow DOM. Ionic does not provide a default date range picker, so I attempted to enhance it by adjusting the border radius to 0. Unfortunately, this customization seems to be restricted within the confines of the Shadow DOM.

Is there a way to overcome these styling limitations in Ionic's date range picker? Are there any workarounds or alternative approaches that would allow me to customize the border radius or apply other styling changes effectively?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can try with part to overwrite styling of some element inside shadow DOM or if possible can you provide DOM SS and for part you can refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part

Comment: *"Ionic does not provide a default date range picker, so I attempted to enhance it by adjusting the border radius to 0."* does not make much sense to me. Consider adding a *runnable* [mcve] (use codesandbox or a similar service) with what you tried and did not work.

Comment: Apologize, basically I want to style a shadow dom from the outside.

Example I want to add more styles in calendar-day.

#shadow-root(open)
<ion-datetime>
<div class="calendar-day">